# "operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" on Oracle reader

Tags: c#, oracle11g, performance-testing, datareader

Here's the crux of it:

I have this script which gave me absolutely no problems until after I ran it through a performance test, and now its' constantly showing me the same error during debug whenever I try to run it:

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection())
{
             //Connect to OracleDB and retreive the first valid, unused SRVID//
            con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhostip)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyServerNAme)));User Id=MyUSer;Password=MyPAssword";
            OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("SELECT MASK_GUID(SWAP_GUID(SRVID)) FROM  MYTable WHERE USED=0 AND ROWNUM = 1", con);
            con.Open();
            OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            ServerID = reader.GetString(0);
            reader.Close();
             //update SRVID in DB as used so further users will not select it
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE MyTable SET USED=1 WHERE SRVID = FIX_GUID('"+ ServerID+"')";
            command.Connection = con;
             command.ExecuteNonQuery();
             reader.Close();
             reader.Dispose();
       con.Close();
       con.Dispose();
}
```

That's the code, here's what goes wrong:

1. on `ServerID= reader.GetString(0)` I receive the *operation is not valid due to the current state of the object* error. When glossing over reader in debug, I see that it has no data rows, which might explain the error (but that leads to...)
2. The query is fine. I run it locally on the database and it returns a valid value ( I copy-pasted it to be sure), so that's not the reason reader has no data.
3. This problem started during a performance test which ran this script about 800 times before this error started to appear constantly... The system which I tested still operates fine, even when performing actions that require access to the same database.

Debugger shows no other errors regarding this case... OR at all, for that matter.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the MaxHttpCollection property to a higher value.